# Multiple checkbox value in PHPMailer displays empty

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, phpmailer

I have set up PHP mailer to deliver contact form information on my website. I am having trouble sorting out the multiple checkbox inputs. It appears empty in emails.
Here the form HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input name="time" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="AM"> AM
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input name="time" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="PM"> PM
            </label>
        </div>
```

In my PHP code, I added below to check if there are inputs for the checkboxes:

```
if($_POST["time"])  {
        $time_array = $_POST['time'];
        $time_tostring = implode(", ", $time_array); 
    }
```

Then in the mail code, I added this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = $config['host'];
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $config['username'];
    $mail->Password = $config['password'];
    $mail->SMTPSecure = $config['secure'];
    $mail->Port = $config['port'];

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($config['from'], $config['fromName']);
    $mail->addAddress($config['sendTo']);
    //$mail->addCC($config['sendToCC']);            
    $mail->addBCC($config['sendToBCC']);            

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Website Contact Form';
    $mail->Body    = '<p>Emptied on: ' . $_POST['day'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Time: "  . $time_tostring . "</p>"        
    . "<p>Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Address: " . $_POST['address'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Phone Number: " . $_POST['number'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Where did you hear about us: " . $_POST['how'] . "</p>"
    . "<p>Service interested in: " . $_POST['comments'] . "</p>"        
    ;

    $mail->send();
    echo json_encode(['status' => true, "data" => 'Message has been sent']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['status' => false, "data" => "Message could not be sent\nMailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo]);
}
```

In the email sent, the time is empty and do not display any value.

I also tried the line below directly but it didn't work too.

```
. "<p>Time: "  . implode(', ', $_POST['time']) . "</p>"
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Any idea is appreciate.

Comment: So far, your question is typo-based. You're using the same name attribute for both checkboxes.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner. I think that is how this work. I checked here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: I know that but you're only going to be overwriting it if you/someone were to check both of those. If you're looking for "one" choice, use a radio button. Or treat your checkboxes as arrays `[]`.

Comment: Honestly, what I said makes more sense than "try this".

Comment: Btw, how can something be both AM *and* PM?

Comment: Thanks. The form is to allow multiple checks. Your comment was helpful.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Client requested it that way.

Comment: Well, your client will eventually find out that what they asked for, will work against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making "time" input fields an array.

```
<input name="time[]" ... >
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I relied on tutorials to come up with the coding and the array part was not mentioned.

Comment: You're welcome, pls upvote. If you're posting multiple fields of the same name (works for any input, select, textarea... not just checkbox), always post them as an array.